# How to get a range from merged cell in excel

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net

I received this excel file from user. It seems was created without any standard pattern. I don't have any idea for getting holidays from this excel.
How to iterate in each month? 
I tried use Excel.Worksheet.Range.Find("January") for getting first cell for start finding in each month.

```
     Dim currentFind As Excel.Range = Nothing
     Dim firstFind As Excel.Range = Nothing
     currentFind = objWs.Range("A1:AM100").Find("January", , _
                    Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, _
                    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, False)
```

But it return cell at "A4" (ROW: 4 , COLUMN: 1) because Title Month cell was merged. I can not use this cell for initial iterating and access to all date in this month. How to know a range between A4 was merged?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.net excel merged cells range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351724/vb-net-excel-merged-cells-range)

Comment: Take a look at `MergeCells` property i.e. you can use: `If currentFind.Mergecells Then`...