# How to get range of merged cell in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I get the range address like ("B4:C4") if B4 is merged with C4.
I can get the address of active cell with `ActiveCell.Address`. Is there any function that can get the range address of a merged cell?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951070/get-start-range-and-end-range-of-a-vertically-merged-cell-with-excel-using-vba

Comment: `ActiveCell.MergeArea.Address`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get start range and end range of a vertically merged cell with Excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951070/get-start-range-and-end-range-of-a-vertically-merged-cell-with-excel-using-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowI As Long, LastRowJ As Long, LastRowMax As Long

    'Change sheet name if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'For testing purposes i use range A1
        If .Range("A1").MergeCells Then
            Debug.Print .Range("A1").MergeArea.Address
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```