# How to Determine the Mode of a group of cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image: Layout of Data - click to see diagram]

I have an excel sheet which contains a column of TEXT data for which I want to determine the MODE (see column marked 'Column Containing Merged Cells' on the right side of the diagram). The MODE is to be determined for a set of cells. The individual set of cells may be identified by the start and end of each the merged cells (see column marked 'Text Containing Cells - Need to determine Mode' at the left side of the diagram).

Note1: I have found the following formula which determines the MODE of a set of text cells e.g. `=INDEX(I2:I7,MODE(MATCH(I2:I7,I2:I7,0)))`
Note2: The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951070/get-start-range-and-end-range-of-a-vertically-merged-cell-with-excel-using-vba) provides some guidance but requires manual entry of the start of each individual merge section.

If you could help provide a formula OR Visual Basic based solution which 'automatically' identifies the MODE value for each set of cells in the data set I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two formula solutions for you to consider.

The first one uses your current data structure.  However, it uses the `OFFSET` function, which is a volatile function.

The second one avoids using `OFFSET`, but would require "normalizing" your data so that each cell in Column A has a value that corresponds with Column E.

Note that with both solutions you'll need to adjust the ranges accordingly.

**Solution 1**

[image]

I2:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A10,"?*")
```

J2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copied down:

```
=IF(ROWS(J$2:J2)<=$I$2,INDEX($A$2:$A$10,SMALL(IF(LEN($A$2:$A$10)>0,ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS(J$2:J2))),"")
```

K2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copied down:

```
=IF(ROWS(K$2:K2)<=$I$2,INDEX($E$2:$E$10,MODE(IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET($A$2:$A$10,,,ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1),"?*")=ROWS(K$2:K2),MATCH($E$2:$E$10,$E$2:$E$10,0)))),"")
```

**Solution 2**

[image]

First, "normalize" Column A as follows...

```
1) Select A2:A10 (adjust the range accordingly).

2) Unmerge those cells `Ribbon >> Home tab >> Alignment group >> click Merge and Center dropdown >> select Unmerge Cells`

3) Select blank cells `Ribbon >> Home tab >> Editing group >> Find and Select >> Got to Special >> select Blanks >> Click OK`

4) Press the `=` key.

5) Press the `Up Arrow` key.

6) Press the `Ctrl` key, and then while the key is pressed down, press the `Enter` key.
```

Then, enter the following formulas...

I2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A2:A10,A2:A10,0),ROW(A2:A10)-ROW(A2)+1)>0,1))
```

J2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copied down:

```
=IF(ROWS(J$2:J2)<=$I$2,INDEX($A$2:$A$10,SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,0),ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1)>0,ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS(J$2:J2))),"")
```

K2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copied down:

```
=IF(ROWS(K$2:K2)<=$I$2,INDEX($E$2:$E$10,MODE(IF($A$2:$A$10=J2,MATCH($E$2:$E$10,$E$2:$E$10,0)))),"")
```

Comment: Both solution worked great. Thank you. Opted to implement the second solution (as you mentioned it was more stable). I should mention that the steps you detailed for solution#2 had a few steps missing. They were:1. Select the columns that have the merged cells.

2. Click Home > Merge & Center > Unmerge Cells.

3. This will result in thethe merged cells have been unmerged and only the first cell will be filled with the original values. Then continue with the steps you have outlined above.Thank you once again.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right, I forgot to include it.  For accuracy and completeness, I'll edit my post accordingly.  Glad you were able to work through it.  Cheers!